# Iterate over an enum, which saves classes, then init the classes and put them into a map

Tags: java, enums

I have made an interface, which my classes implement, and I have an enum with counstructor which takes a `Class<?>` as an arguement. Something like `Enum(Class<?> class)`, and the enum has a function to return that class. How can I make so that `class` arguement must implement my interface, and how do I later loop through `values()` of the enum, get the classes, init them and put them into a HashMap.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [upper bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) on the wildcard:

```
Class<? extends YourInterface>
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I later in a for loop init them, and put them in a HashMap<MyEnumConstant, MyInterface>? Thanks for a quick answer.

Comment: If `clazz` is an instance of `Class<? extends MyInterface>`, then the result of `clazz.newInstance()` is an instance of `MyInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum MyEnum {

  VALUE_1(ClassA.class);

  private Class<? extends MyItf> clazz;

  MyEnum(Class<? extends MyItf> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public Class<? extends MyItf> getClazz() {
    return clazz;
  }
}
```

Then loop on `enum.values()` :

```
Map<MyEnum, Class> map = new HashMap<>();

for(MyEnum e : MyEnum.values()) {
  map.put(e, e.getClazz());
}
```